# Truncate command not creating a hole

Tags: linux, files, btrfs, sparse-files, truncate

I am trying to create a file with hole using the truncate command. I read up in some posts and one of the answers in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518559/what-are-the-holes-in-files-created-with-fallocate) says to use truncate command. Filesystem used is btrfs. This is the command

```
$: truncate -s 16K holes

$: du holes
$: 16      holes
$:  stat holes
File: holes
  Size: 16384           Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

As can be seen, its allocating 16 blocks...my understanding was that it will allocate 0 blocks as mentioned that answer as well. Did I make a mistake in understanding what truncate is doing?

Comment: What is the filesystem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski its a normal centos /dev/vda3

Comment: That still does not answer what filesystem is used. You can show that by running `mount |grep vda3`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it shows a lot of output, but btrfs is probably what you are asking?

Comment: You could just edit the output into your question, but yes, btrfs sounds reasonable.

Comment: An existing non-sparse big file can be truncated with `truncate` to a smaller size and it will not become sparse. The method you used creates sparseness when `truncate` creates a new file (or extends an existing file). Are you sure your `truncate` created `holes` from nothing? Try with a file that doesn't exist yet and confirm the issue.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I ran truncate command on a file which didn't exist..i.e. in this case holes files did not exist before..

Comment: Does `crc32 holes` print `ab54d286`? What if you do `fallocate -d holes`? Is the file sparse now?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your findings:

```
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x   2 tink tink  4096 2023-10-06 05:45 .
drwxr-x--- 180 tink tink 20480 2023-10-06 05:30 ..
$ truncate -s 16K holes
$ du holes
0   holes
$ stat holes
  File: holes
  Size: 16384       Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 46402746    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  tink)   Gid: ( 1000/  tink)
Access: 2023-10-06 05:46:36.012153267 +1300
Modify: 2023-10-06 05:46:36.012153267 +1300
Change: 2023-10-06 05:46:36.012153267 +1300
 Birth: -
$
```

Are you sure you're using `btrfs` (which supposedly supports sparseness, I can't confirm as I'm on `ext4`) and not something like `vfat`?

Comment: yes I am using btrfs...I get this filesystem name when I run mount | grep vda3. Is there any other way to know?

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. Most likely unrelated, but what virtualisation platform are you running your centos under?